# События отрабатывают самостоятельно WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, события

В общем, столкнулся я с NullReferenceException и, в результате (длительной) отладки, обнаружил, что обработчик событий `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` вызывает метод-обработчик при старте приложения.
Разметка ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="comboBox" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    Margin="5" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="150" 
    SelectedIndex="0" 
    SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
```

По идее такого не должно быть, или я ошибаюсь? Если нужны какие-то части программного кода, пишите, отвечу.

Comment: Есть такой код `var a=42;`, но где то что то не работает. Если нужны другие части - пишите, отвечу.

Comment: Вопрос по моему очевиден, должен ли обработчик событий ComboBox.SelectionChanged вызывать методы при старте приложения, если нигде в коде не меняется SelectedItem этого ComboBox?

Comment: Нет, обработчик `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` должен вызываться только тогда, когда меняется ссылка на выделенный элемент в этом комбобоксе. Это никак не связано с фактом старта приложения.

Comment: <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged"> При таком описании ComboBox'a, вызывается ли обработчик?

Comment: Добавляйте код, что считаете нужным, в вопрос - комментарии далеко не все будут читать. Но так и не ясно откуда ваша проблема. Может быть из за этого `SelectedIndex="0"`, а может и нет. Ставьте точку останова внутри обработчика и смотрите стек вызовов.

Comment: [crash](http://oi66.tinypic.com/23rjxc4.jpg) Вот такое вот происходит, когда я ставлю брейкпоинт в обработчике. Студия при этом виснит намертво на минут 7.

Comment: Срабатывание происходит, по-видимому из-за этого `SelectedIndex="0"`. Уберите эту строку из XAML.

Comment: Хм, но мне нужно, чтобы при старте выделение было на первом элементе. Придётся костылить обработчик?

Comment: А покажите StackTrace. У исключения есть свойство StackTrace, добавьте его к вопросу.

Comment: @VladD В поза предыдущем моём комментарии ссылка на скриншот "crush", такая штука происходит при попытках дебага обработчика. StackTrace как и всё остальное не достать. Хотя, попробую запасной вариант

Comment: @VladD И так, вот что мне удалось достать... [photo(click)](http://oi64.tinypic.com/2isfwio.jpg)    Не сложно догадаться, много информации не даст. Есть ещё идеи?

Comment: @eXCore: Залогируйте `ex.StackTrace`. Там будет одна большая строка, которая содержит вообще всё, что вам надо.

Comment: @VladD [click](http://oi68.tinypic.com/es1e90.jpg) К сожалению, это всё.

Comment: 56 строка - деление на ноль

Comment: @eXCore: WarframeMarket :) Окей, а что находится в строке 56 файла MainWindow.xaml.cs?

Comment: @eXCore: Ага, вижу. Ну так вы в предыдущей строке делите на ноль. А из-за чего было исключение в вопросе?

Comment: @VladD Ну да, но по другому я не знаю как выследить StackTrace(кроме как вызвав исключение), когда происходит это "лишнее" срабатывание при запуске программы. (как уже писал - брейкпоинты рушат студию xD)

Comment: @VladD исключение в вопросе возникает из-за того, что происходит "лишний" вызов обработчика и в итоге 2 разных потока пытаются сконстуировать объект. Ну, с того что я мог понял, локализовав исключение, оно происходило при создании Image из BitmapImage(который загружается по заданой ссылке)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию ни один элемент не выделен. При этом `SelectedIndex` равен `-1`.

Если вы меняете его на 0, то, разумеется, вызовется обработчик — вы ведь сами это попросили!

Если это нежелательно, можно сделать, например, следующее:

1. Вы можете завести булев флаг, и взвести его в конструкторе, после `InitializeComponent` (этот метод считывает и интерпретирует XAML). Флаг можно проверить в обработчике.
2. Вы можете подписаться на изменения в code-behind вручную, после `InitializeComponent`.
3. Вы можете проанализировать в обработчике предыдущее состояние выделенного элемента, заглянув в [`SelectionChangedEventArgs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.7).
4. Вы можете сделать код обработчика более общим, чтобы он не падал, будучи вызванным в момент, когда ни один элемент не отмечен.

Я бы порекомендовал попробовать последний вариант.

Comment: А если у вас падает студия от breakpoint'ов, срочно переинсталлируйте Студию. Без хорошо работающего отладчика жить невозможно.

Comment: Это был единственный раз, когда у меня упала студия из-за брейкпоинта. Думаю, если сделать minimum-requirement example, это можно использовать для баг репорта. И да, второй вариант как раз что надо, спасибо. И на счёт падений, там всё сделано безопасно по отношению к null'ам.

Comment: @eXCore: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!